# Reverse field to serializer DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have models:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Reservation(models.Model):

    start = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='reservations')
```

and serializer:

class ReservationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

```
order_first_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
order_last_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
order_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = ('id',
              'start',
              'end',
              'order',
              'order_first_name',
              'order_last_name',
              'order_id',

              )
    read_only_fields = ('order', 'order_first_name', 'order_last_name', 'order_id')
```

The problem is I can't see both `order_first_name` and `order_last_name` in API response as well as no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this works

order_first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='order.first_name', read_only=True)